# guacamole common multiple sessions

Tags: angular, spring-boot, guacamole, guacamole-common.js

I am using the guacamole common library in a spring boot application with an angular frontend. We create the vnc tunnels over an endpoint extending the GuacamoleHTTPTunnelServlet. We built the start application according to [this guide](https://guacamole.apache.org/doc/gug/writing-you-own-guacamole-app.html) and extended it now according to our needs.

It currently works fine, the problem is as soon as a user reloads or leaves and re-enters the webpage with the vnc tunnel integrated. So it seems that there is a conflict with the tunnel sessions for a user. How can I properly manage these sessions? Is there an example somewhere? I think a tokenbased approach can solve this issue - I gave it already a try but I have problems with persisting these GuacamoleTunnel objects.

This is my controller method:

```
@Override
  protected GuacamoleTunnel doConnect(HttpServletRequest request) throws GuacamoleException {
    String user = request.getUserPrincipal().getName();
    LOGGER.info("Creating tunnel for user {}.", user);

    if (tunnelSessionManager.getTunnel(user) != null) {
      // If a tunnel already exists for the user, close it
      LOGGER.trace("Tunnel already exists for user {}. Closing tunnel.", user);
      tunnelSessionManager.closeTunnel(user);
    }

    GuacamoleConfiguration config = prepareConfiguration(request);

    try {
      // Connect to guacd, proxying a connection to the VNC server above
      GuacamoleSocket socket = connectToGuacD(config);

      // Create tunnel from now-configured socket
      SimpleGuacamoleTunnel tunnel = new SimpleGuacamoleTunnel(socket);
      // Associate the tunnel with the user's id
      tunnelSessionManager.associateTunnel(user, tunnel);

      return tunnel;
    } catch (GuacamoleException e) {
      LOGGER.error("Error while creating tunnel.", e);
      return null;
    }
  }
```